# Como deixar uma div fixa acompanhando o scroll?

Tags: angularjs, posicionamento, angular-material

Estou usando `AngularJs` e `Angular Material` e preciso fazer uma `div` ficar fixa porém não faço a menor ideia de como fazer, minha estrutura é a seguinte:

```
<div class="page">
    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <md-button hide-gt-sm class="menu" ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')" aria-label="Show User List">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="menu"></md-icon>
        </md-button>

        <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">{{pageTitle}}</h2>

        <md-input-container md-theme="input">
            <input style="border-color: #fff; font-size: 14px; color: #fff; width: 200px;" ng-model="search"
                   aria-label="Buscar pergunta">
        </md-input-container>
        <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-right: 40px;" aria-hidden="true"
           title="Buscar perguntas"></i>
    </md-toolbar>

    <div ng-cloak class="tabsdemoDynamicHeight">
        <md-content>
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
                <md-tab label="Todos">
                    <md-content>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div ng-show="diference > 0" class="text-center"> //essa é a div que quero deixar fixa
                                <a href="" ng-click="getAll()">{{diference}} novas perguntas</a>
                            </div>
                            <md-card ng-repeat="question in questions | filter:search | limitTo:limitAll" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                <md-card-content ng-click="navigateTo('/questions/answers/' + question.id)">

 //Continuação
```

*A `div` que quero deixar fixa acompanhando o scroll é essa:*

```
<div ng-show="diference > 0" class="text-center">
                                    <a href="" ng-click="getAll()">{{diference}} novas perguntas</a>
</div>
```

Alguma maneira de fazer?

Comment: Não dá pra usar `position: fixed` do css?

Comment: @Marconi já tentei, mas não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar position: fixed? Pode utilizar affix do Bootstrap e definir a partir de onde ficará fixo.

Exemplo:

```
z-index: 11;
position: fixed;
top: calc(50vh - 86px);
right: 1%;
```

Este CSS deixará fixo, centralizado e alinhado à direita.

Ou poderá utilizar o Affix, segue link para visualização:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-affix

Exemplo funcionando
http://jsfiddle.net/nick_v6/cub6yhwe/

Mais exemplos:
http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

Comment: O exemplo apenas deixou fixa, mas não acompanha o scroll, não estou utilizando bootstrap no projeto, apenas o Angular Material